# Driver's door not closing on VW Golf mk4

Tags: vw, golf, mk4

The driver's door on my VW Golf mk4 is not closing from time to time specially when it's specially cold. The door opens just fine, but then I'm not able to close it unless I reposition the *hook* on the closing mechanism on the door, so it can *catch* the metal ring on the door's frame and the door closes. Until do that door isn't closing and just bounces back. You can see an image of the hook I'm taking about below.

[image: door locking mechanism]

I applied some WD-40 also to try to make to move things along, but I don't know if it's a solution that it's going to last.

I would bet that the main problem is dirtiness. Old grease and dust mixed that with the cold gets really hard and keep the mechanism from working properly. I'm thinking to use a brush and gas —lighter fluid— that have helped me to clean this kind of thing in the past quite well.

On the rear passenger door seems that problem is the opposite one. The door is not opening and not until I open an closes a couple of times the door not open. This door didn't lock in the past in some occasion and the problem seemed to be fixed after a applied oil.

Are my door locks mechanism just dirty and acting up just because the cold weather or these things can be broken since the car is almost 15 years old?

Comment: I'm only guessing now, but either your mechanism is so worn that the catch for the locker doesn't catch it after the door has been opened. But if your lucky it's just dirt, or maybe some spring that has let go. Start by making sure you know how the mechanism work, then see if you can clean it in some way. If that doesn't work you'll might have to take it out of the door to fix it. And worst case, just change for another one.
Often a failing door can be a misalignment, but it doesn't sound like it in this case.. but it's hard to know from just text...

Comment: Yeah… I understand that it's really difficult to just know by the text and the picture. It usually happens then it's really cold —subzero temps— but not always. I just guess that it's just the mix of dirt and cold.

Comment: In that case I'm quite confident that it's a dirt/lubrication issue. Not quite sure what lubrication you should use though... I would try with 5-56/lockspray or similar. There is a chance that dry lubrication is recommended (graphite powder). I don't think you should use fatty oils, because they collect dirt, and might freeze in the cold.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the locking mechanism have moved a bit in,it is possible to adjust this.

The mechanism can be moved by loosening the two bolts,you will only need to loosen the bolts a little.

The mechanism can be moved up-down and in-out,move it slightly out 2MM or so and tighten the bolts a little and close the door,when you now open the door the lock mechanism should be in the right possion tighten the bolts and you are done.

there is other ways to do this so find a way that works fo you.

Comment: Are the bolts what made the mechanism to move or just keep it in place?

Comment: the bolts keep the mechanism in place,if the mechanism is in closed position and you try to close the door the locking mechanism might be knocked out of position this is often the root cause for this type of problem.

Comment: but do you think the mechanism just move —slightly— so I have to put it in place and them tights the bolds or it just moved from the position? I ask because it looks like the mechanism is tightly hold and it's just that sometimes it gets stuck in the wrong position.

Comment: a slight movement is all it takes for the mechanism to randomly fail to engage fully.you might take a look at the bolts and see if they have comme loose if they are it will be an easy fix.